# If I compare two actions, the first one of which is expressed in infinitive with particle 'to', can I use a gerund for the second action?

Tags: grammar

If I compare two actions, the first one of which is expressed in infinitive with particle 'to', can I use a gerund for the second action or should I stick to infinitive?

For example, can I say:

> She likes to listen more than speaking.

or should I stick to:

> She likes to listen more than to speak.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a general principle that structures that are closely coordinated, like "A and/or B", and "A more than B", should observe parallelism, meaning that A and B should use the same form. It's more important in writing than in speech. It isn't a matter of grammar, but of esthetics and ease of understanding. The use of the same form underlines the relation between A and B.

Another natural expression of your example with parallelism might be "She likes listening more than speaking.

Comment: But does "She likes to listen more than to speak" sound natural?

Comment: Yes, it's natural enough.

Comment: +1, great explanation